# Haskell: Defining strict data

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation

I've been trying to make a class of 'Strictable' types. The reason being is that I want to define something like this:

```
foldl'' f z = foldl' f (make_strict z)
```

So when `fold''` is used on a `strictable` type, there won't be unevaluated thunks.

So I've started with the following:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

class Strictable a where
  type Strict a :: *
  make_strict :: a -> Strict a
```

Defining instances for `Int`s and `Float`s is easy, `foldl'` works fine with these already, so there's nothing to do.

```
instance Strictable Int where
  type Strict Int = Int
  make_strict = id

instance Strictable Float where
  type Strict Float = Float
  make_strict = id
```

Here is the tricky part. `foldl'` only unwraps the outer most constructor, so with a pair for example, you can still get space leaks using `foldl'`. I want to create a strict pair out of an ordinary pair. So I tried this:

```
instance (Strictable a, Strictable b) => Strictable (a, b) where
  type Strict (a, b) = (! Strict a, ! Strict b)
  make_strict (x1, x2) = (make_strict x1, make_strict x2)
```

Unfortunately I got a bunch of compile errors. How should I implement this?

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for something [like this](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/adaptive-containers/0.3/doc/html/Data-Adaptive-Tuple.html)? I.e. using associated *data*, not type synonyms.

```
instance AdaptPair Bool Bool where
  data Pair Bool Bool = PBool {-# UNPACK #-}!Int {-# UNPACK #-}!Int

  fst (PBool x _) = Prelude.toEnum x
  snd (PBool _ x) = Prelude.toEnum x
  curry f x y    =  f (PBool (Prelude.fromEnum x) (Prelude.fromEnum y))
```

You will need to use associated data types, not type synonyms, to add the required strictness annotations. And while you're there, you may as well explicitly unpack for some of the monomorophic types.

Generic instances that just add bang patterns are easy after that.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, and my understanding of [parallel strategies](http://community.haskell.org/~simonmar/papers/strategies.pdf) (PDF link) doesn't fail me, then parallel strategies can implement your `make_strict` straightforwardly; see the [`parallel` package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parallel) for the API and implementation of parallel strategies.

In fact, the [`rdeepseq` strategy](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parallel/3.2.0.3/doc/html/Control-Parallel-Strategies.html#v%3ardeepseq) from [`Control.Parallel.Strategies`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parallel/3.2.0.3/doc/html/Control-Parallel-Strategies.html) might be exactly what you're looking for.

In spite of "parallel" in the name, it's really *evaluation* strategies implemented by exploiting laziness to declaratively specify a computation and then recursively descending down a data structure to selectively apply functions like `seq`, `par` and `pseq` to its elements.

Comment: Yes, his strictness type class is basically [the `Eval` class from Haskell 1.2](http://www.haskell.org/definition/from12to13.html#strict) -- and par strategies are strongly related to that.